# Excel formula to space out range depending on other variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Right - this is a tricky one to phrase so I'm going to use a couple of images to help me.

In Columns A and B is a varying list of team names and the number of players each team has.

Column D contains the desired output.

I need a formula, to be inserted into Cell D2 and dragged down as far as the total of Column B, to return the team names - **but crucially** to allow a number of rows beneath which return blank. The number of blank rows beneath is effectively equal to 1 - the number of players in that team.

[image: Excel formula to space out range depending on other variable]

I have given it some thought, but can't come up with a suitable formula. Any ideas?

Also suggestions for a better title are welcome.

Comment: Can you use VBA for it?

Comment: I wouldn't be averse to it I guess, just thought a formula could be better.

Comment: I think a formula, if possible, will be way too complex. Instead go for a VBA function.

Comment: I've posted some code below. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following VBA function will do exactly what you want. Let me know if any part of it is not clear to you.

```
Sub teamRows()

Dim colDRowNumber As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim teamName As String
Dim numberOfRows As Integer
Dim HowFar As Integer

' Loop through the teams in column A
HowFar = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

' Variable to keep count of rows in column D
colDRowNumber = 2

For i = 2 To HowFar

    ' Get the team's name and number of rows
    teamName = Range("A" & i).Value
    numberOfRows = Range("B" & i).Value

    ' Fill in the team's name in column D
    Range("D" & colDRowNumber).Value = teamName

    ' Increase the row number by the number of empty rows required
    colDRowNumber = colDRowNumber + numberOfRows

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks great, why is the colDRowNumber variable set to '2' though?

Comment: Starting from the second row.. the team names and their corresponding numbers start from the second row.

Comment: colDRowNumber also starts from second row because you input the team names starting from the second row.

Comment: Thanks. In my example I've started the team names at row two, in my working document I am actually starting the team names at row 50, with some other content which is not part of this example above. Your code works perfectly in my example document, but can it be made to work with X number of rows of content above it, by specifying a starting row?

Comment: Yes just change the variables i and colDRowNumber to the 50.

Answer (score 0):

A complex but short attempt - I wanted to avoid loops.

Example below works on A2 to A20

```
y = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=index(substitute(substitute(substitute(REPT(A2:A20 &"","",B2:B20),A2:A20&"","",""X"",1),A2:A20,""""),""X"",A2:a20),0,1)")), ","), ",")
[d2].Resize(UBound(y)) = Application.Transpose(y)
```